# jQuery: how to stop a user triggering the same event before the first one one is finished

Tags: jquery

I am making a portfolio site for a friend and I have come across a small problem when I animate an element using jQuery.

Here is my development site http://dotlinesquare.phpfogapp.com/portfolio/gaze the control buttons are at the black header.

The problem is if I click the button while the event is taken place it messes up the position number.

Here is the code hopefully it will help you understand my problem

```
$('#next').click(function() {
    var currentMargin = $('#slider').attr('style');

    var number = currentMargin.match(/-?[0-9]+/);
    var position = number - 993;

    $('#slider').animate({ 
        marginLeft: position,
    }, 1000, 'easeInQuad', function() {
        console.log('done');
    });
});
$('#back').click(function() {
    var currentMargin = $('#slider').attr('style');

    var number = currentMargin.match(/-?[0-9]+/);
    var num = new Number(number)
    var position = num + 993;
    console.log(position);
    $('#slider').animate({ 
        marginLeft: position,
    }, 500, 'easeInQuad', function() {
        console.log('done');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the status of your 2 click functions using [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) and check if it's in progress first before running the action.  Like this:

```
  $('#next').click(function() {
    if ( $("#slider").data('inprogress') != true ) {

        $("#slider").data('inprogress',true);

        var currentMargin = $('#slider').attr('style');

        var number = currentMargin.match(/-?[0-9]+/);
        var position = number - 993;

        $('#slider').animate({ 
            marginLeft: position,
        }, 1000, 'easeInQuad', function() {
            console.log('done');
            $("#slider").data('inprogress',false);
        });

      }
  });
  $('#back').click(function() {
    if ( $("#slider").data('inprogress') != true ) {

        $("#slider").data('inprogress',true);


        var currentMargin = $('#slider').attr('style');

        var number = currentMargin.match(/-?[0-9]+/);
        var num = new Number(number)
        var position = num + 993;
        console.log(position);
        $('#slider').animate({ 
            marginLeft: position,
        }, 500, 'easeInQuad', function() {
            console.log('done');
            $("#slider").data('inprogress',false);
        });
    }

  });
```

Comment: That worked a treat! But before I saw you answer I started on a new way to solve the problem, ill post it below! Thanks for your help I didn't know about using .data()

Comment: Or I will in 7 hours when I can self-answer  :P